# The gitlab Pipeline fails (because of docker rate limit)

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline

I have a `gitlab-ci.yml` in my project.

It was passed, after every merge.

But today it faces this error:

```
Preparing the "docker" executor
00:31
Using Docker executor with image maven:3.6.3-jdk-11 ...
Pulling docker image maven:3.6.3-jdk-11 ...
ERROR: Preparation failed: Error response from daemon: toomanyrequests: You have reached your pull rate limit. You may increase the limit by authenticating and upgrading: https://www.docker.com/increase-rate-limit (docker.go:131:3s)
Will be retried in 3s ...
```

What can I do for solving this?

Comment: https://www.docker.com/increase-rate-limits

Comment: You should always use local cached docker image instead of pulling it from server every time.

Comment: @tentative I can't upgrade the docker to the pro version. :(

Comment: Typically docker caches image locally unless you preform some specific cleanup after image is not needed anymore. Alternatively you can setup local Docker registry server to keep all the necessary images there.

Comment: It is mostly about your gitlab runner setup, not about ci file.